# efs problem (emergency calls only)

Tags: samsung

I used to do a full factory wipe then flashed a stock firmware with Odin, that helped me get back to having access to my mobile network then I flashed to Resurrection Remix 5.5.3 and lost access to my mobile network (Emergency Calls Only) I checked my IMEI and it appears to be valid. I didn't backup my /efs I didn't do anything to it. What seems to be the solution? I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 (I-9300)

Comment: I also tried contacting my phone after going back to the stock fw and it seems that everytime I make a call to my phone it dials but nothing appears on my phone, I also tried texting but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I owned a Samsung phone this too would happen to me. I would have to flash a stock TW based rom and see if the network connection comes back. If so, I would boot into recovery and make a backup of EFS. Then reflash the custom rom, Then restore the EFS backup after you flashed the custom rom.

Comment: What do you mean by flashing a "TW" based rom? I tried flashing a stock rom based on my country and my carrier but to no avail.